# Stuck on login screen!

Tags: lubuntu, login, upstart, session

I have only one user account on Lubuntu 13.10 and the automatic access was enabled. I decided to change this option; I wanted to see the login screen on startup where I can choose the user and run the session only typing my password.

I went to **Menu > Preferences > Default applications for LXSession > Settings** and ticked the **Upstart Session** option. After reboot I can see the login screen, I can choose between my account and the guest one, I select my account, I type the password, it takes it, it seems for one second to load the session, the panel... but it takes me immediately back to the login screen!

I can't get in my account any more! I guess I have to modify (with a live session) some files in the `/usr/share/upstart/session` folder, but I don't know how. Or maybe I can log in to my account in another way, then change the *Upstart Session* option!

What should I do?

Comment: Where do you see "Upstart Session"?

Comment: This works in lubuntu 14.04 also, just needed to do the same.

Comment: @karel I don’t think this is a duplicate. OP posted a meaningful [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/414967/250300) which is different from the general advice on the [linked page](https://askubuntu.com/q/223501/250300). Moreover, the asker here _knows_ what caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it!

I changed the line `upstart_user_session=` from `true` to `false` in the `desktop.conf` file. It is located in `/home/username/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu`.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer (✓). [Self answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) and accepting them are OK here!